# My cat loves faucet water, but not cat fountain...why?

Tags: cats

My cat has always loved to drink from the running tub faucet...for SEVERAL YEARS.  But this doesn't help the water bill or the environment, so I bought him a stainless steel cat fountain.  He was curious and drank from it as soon as I got it ready, cleaned and set up.  He has never gone back to it since.  He ignores it like it isn't even there and will sit on the edge of the tub begging me to turn on the tub faucet.  I take him over to the fountain and he walks away.  I have had it now for several months (can't send it back for refund),keeping it filled, constantly running, and I clean it as suggested every two weeks, hoping he will change his mind, but to no avail. Do other cats do this or is mine just weird?

Answer (score 3):

Our cats (well, two of them) initially avoided their drinking fountain because of the humming of the motor pump.

Other than the material of the bowl itself (like Mick mentioned), see if they drink from it when the fountain is not turned on, because it might be the pump that does it.

Answer (score 2):

Some cats do not like drinking out of metal containers, possibly because they impart a metallic taste or smell. When I got him, my cat refused to drink out of a stainless steel food bowl, and would go outside to drink from puddles. As soon as I got him a ceramic bowl, he was fine. Will your water fountain accept a non-metallic bowl?